# Strong operator convergence in $B(C_{per}^1[-π, π], C[-π, π])$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C_{per}^1[-π, π]$ be the subspace of the space $C^1[−π,π]$ consisting of all functions satisfying the conditions $x(-π) = x(π)$, $x^{'}(-π) = x^{'}(π)$.

Consider the operator $A_n \in B(C_{per}^1[-π, π], C[-π, π])$ defined by $$(A_nx)(t) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^n(a_kcos(kt) + b_ksin(kt)),$$ where
$$a_k = \frac{1}{π}\int_{-π}^{π}x(t)cos(kt)dt, \quad b_k = \frac{1}{π}\int_{-π}^{π}x(t)sin(kt)dt.$$
Hence $A_nx$ is the partial sum of the Fourier series for the function $x$

$C_{per}^1[a, b]$ is a subspace of the space $C^1[a,b]$ consisting of functions whose values at the points $a$ and $b$ coincide.

I know, that $A_n \xrightarrow{s} J$, where $J: C_{per}^1[-π, π] \rightarrow C[-π, π], Jx = x$. However I'm unable to prove that, can somebody help me? Thank you!

An operator sequence $(A_n) \in B(X, Y)$ converges strongly to $A$, (we write $A_n \xrightarrow{s} J$), if forall $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in X$, for all large enough $n$, $\|A_nx - Ax\|_Y < \epsilon$.

Comment: write down the definition of "s" convergence in this case

Comment: @Exxod supplemented a question

Comment: you miss a "definitively in $n$"  somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in C^1_{\rm per}[-\pi,\pi].$ Denote by $\tilde{a}_k$ and $\tilde{b}_k$  the Fourier coefficients of $x'.$ Then applying the integration by parts gives
$$a_k={1\over \pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi x(t)\cos kt\,dt=
-{1\over k\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi x'(t)\sin kt\,dt=-{\tilde{b}_k\over k}$$
Similarly
$$b_k={1\over k\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi x'(t)\cos kt\,dt={\tilde{a}_k\over k}$$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {|\tilde{b}_k|\over k}\le \left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\tilde{b}_k|^2\right )^{1/2}\left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over k^2}\right )^{1/2}<\infty$$
Similarly $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |b_k|<\infty$$ Therefore the Fourier series of $x$ is convergent absolutely and uniformly to $x$, by the Weierstrass test. Equivalently $\|A_nx- x\|_\infty \to 0.$