# Uniform operator convergence in $B(C_{per}^1[-π, π], C[-π, π])$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $C_{per}^1[-π, π]$ be the subspace of the space $C^1[−π,π]$ consisting of all functions satisfying the conditions $x(-π) = x(π)$, $x^{'}(-π) = x^{'}(π)$.

Consider the operator $A_n \in B(C_{per}^1[-π, π], C[-π, π])$ defined by $$(A_nx)(t) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^n(a_kcos(kt) + b_ksin(kt)),$$ where
$$a_k = \frac{1}{π}\int_{-π}^{π}x(t)cos(kt)dt, \quad b_k = \frac{1}{π}\int_{-π}^{π}x(t)sin(kt)dt.$$
Hence $A_nx$ is the partial sum of the Fourier series for the function $x$

$C_{per}^1[a, b]$ is a subspace of the space $C^1[a,b]$ consisting of functions whose values at the points $a$ and $b$ coincide.

[Strong operator convergence in $B(C_{per}^1[-π, π], C[-π, π])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594539/strong-operator-convergence-in-bc-per1-%cf%80-%cf%80-c-%cf%80-%cf%80)
In this question, the strong convergence of the operator was considered. I thought of an example that would show that there is no uniform convergence, but I couldn't come up with one, can somebody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what norms you are using, so I will assume.

Fix $n$. If you take $g(x)=\frac1{n+2}\sin((n+1)x)$ then $\|g\|=1$ and
$$
\|g-A_ng\|=\|g\|=1. 
$$
This shows that $\|I-A_n\|\geq1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Could you explain why does the norm of the function above is equal to 1?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you never said what the norms are, so I had to guess. Being that one usually considers norms between complete spaces, I assumed that the spaces were complete. The canonical norm that makes C$^1$ complete is $\|g\|=\|g\|_\infty+\|g'\|_\infty$.

Comment: So sorry for that, norm is $\|g\|$$_{C_[-\pi, \pi]}$ + $\|$$g^{'}$$\|$$_{C_[-pi, pi]}$. But if i will use this form, then how do we get that norm of the function above is equal to zero?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, what is equal to zero?

Comment: My fault, I mean why does the norm of the function above equals to 1?

Comment: I mistyped the normalization coefficient, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Could you explain why this holds: $$
\|g-A_ng\|=\|g\|=1. 
$$?

Comment: $A_ng=0$. $ \ \ \ \ $